# Multiple commands in variable?

Tags: linux, shell-script, dash

Is it possible to execute multiple commands stored in a variable?
Singe command works fine

```
variable="echo HELLO"
$variable
```

> HELLO

I would like to have something like this

```
variable="echo HELLO; echo WORLD"
```

> HELLO
>
> WORLD

not

> HELLO; echo WORLD

Comment: @jesse_b Yes, thank you. All I needed was 'eval $cmd' instead of plain '$cmd'.

Comment: That is probably not what you should have concluded after reading the duplicate.

Comment: What would be the correct conclusion then?

Comment: The correct conclusion, IMO, is that there is almost never a reason to store a command in a variable.  This could be a function or even an alias

Comment: Yes, I understand and agree with that, but this time I have a reason ;)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use arrays (which is not really a single variable...)

```
cmds_array+=( 'echo "Hello"' )
cmds_array+=( 'echo "World ..."' )
for cmd in "${cmds_array[@]}"; do $cmd ; done
```

or: parse your variable with awk (but may be less portable: lots of things could contain a ";" and not be a command separator....)

```
execute_all_cmds () {
  awk -v cmds="${1}" '
     BEGIN { n=split(cmds, cmd, ";")
             for(i=1; i<=n; i++) { system( cmd[i] ) }
      } '
}

cmds='echo "hello" ; echo "World"'

execute_all_cmds "$cmds"
```

Comment: `do $cmd` applies split+glob on `$cmd` and executes the resulting words as a simple command, so assuming an unmodified `$IFS`, `echo "Hello"` output `"Hello"` not `Hello`.

Comment: `awk`'s `system("code")` invokes `sh -c code`, so you might as well do `system(cmds)` here, or `sh -c "$cmds"` as `awk` is pointless or `eval "$cmds"` for the current shell to evaluate that code.

Comment: Also beware that awk's `-v` mangles backslashes, and backslashes are common in shell code, arbitrary data should be passed via `ENVIRON[]` or `ARGV[]`, not `-v`

Comment: Still better not to store commands in a variable in the first place. That's what a function is for